# Keep someone hanging

Tags: idioms, slang

I know that the proper idiom is 'to leave someone hanging' but can one use 'to keep someone hanging' in certain contexts.
Like, does this example sound correct- "You've kept us hanging for a while now; when do you think you would be able to deliver".

Comment: There was a song in the 80s  ["You keep me hangin' on" (Kim Wilde)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJZF-skCY-M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d say they’re used interchangeably, but if you analyze them, they’re slightly different. To “leave someone hanging” I feel is more about walking away and leaving them to wonder while “keeping someone hanging” is more for when they’re holding on, waiting anxiously for an answer or something you’re withholding. I don’t think most people would analyze this, though. Great question.